# C++ Clearing vector of pointers to dynamically-allocated object causes exception?

Tags: c++, exception, pointers, vector, erase

I have a class called `ClassA`. This `ClassA` holds a vector of pointers to dynamically allocated objects of class `ClassB`. The destructor for `ClassA` looks like this:

```
ClassA::~ClassA() {
    for (vector<ClassB*>::iterator i = m_vActiveB.begin(), e = m_vActiveB.end(); i != e; ) {
        vector<ClassB*>::iterator tmp(i++);
        delete *tmp;
        m_vActiveB.erase(tmp);
    }
}
```

In `ClassC`, I have an vector of `ClassA` objects. My current scenario is this: if I don't have any `ClassA` objects in my `ClassC` vector, then it all works fine. But if I have objects in there, and then call .erase() on my vector in `ClassC`, then an exception is thrown. Through logging I have determined that the `ClassA` destructor is called (as it should be, as my understanding is that `.erase()` destroys each vector member), but the exception is thrown when the loop begins.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you holding pointers to dynamically allocated objects in the first place?

Comment: Should I not be doing that? :S

Comment: @user1014679 well, `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are your friends, if you use one of them, you don't even have to iterate the vector destroying each of the members.

Comment: @user1014679, no. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23676606/493122).

Answer (score 4):

Follow the [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) and just use the following to declare your `m_vActiveB` member vector:

```
std::vector<ClassB> m_vActiveB;
```

and let the default constructor take care of destruction. You could alternatively use a vector of [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), but, just like your current solution, you would not take advantage of the natural efficiency of contiguous elements in arrays.

> In my system objects of ClassB themselves need to be constantly, added, removed and updated from the vector to keep a state model.

If your data model doesn't naturally base on the fact that elements are contiguous and have a particular order, an "unsorted", associative container like `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_set` might be a better solution here, especially if you insert and remove the elements that aren't residing at the end of the vector (and sit in the middle instead).

You might also want to take a look at [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which offer, respectively, fast insertion and deletion (which don't invalidate iterators) and fast insertion and deletion at both ends (which don't invalidate iterators either).

> I recall that altering the vector contents invalidates all pointers.. is that correct?

If you call [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) yes, all iterators will get invalidated (including the past the end iterator). Calling `erase` will also make all references and pointers to the deleted object invalid (just like referencing any object that is destroyed/deallocated is invalid).

Comment: Okay it seems like a vector of objects rather than pointers is the most popular solution. Question: will there be any complications if I still handled pointers to the objects in the vector? I recall that altering the vector contents invalidates all pointers.. is that correct?

Comment: @user1014679 Don't use pointers at all, unless you have a good reason. (in 2 years I still have to find one). As far as the second question goes: what do you mean by "altering the vector contents"?

Comment: So how would I edit one of the vector-stored objects?

Comment: In my system objects of ClassB themselves need to be constantly, added, removed and updated from the vector to keep a state model.

Comment: @user1014679 Just the very same? `std::vector::operator[]` returns a *non-const* reference.

Comment: @user1014679: Yes, you would have to be careful of pointer invalidation. One way to dodge this problem is to use "smart pointers"- they can give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: @user1014679, `m_vActiveB[i]` will return a *reference* to the stored `i`th element of the vector. You can modify it however you want. Of course, to delete it you should delete it from the vector (possibly using `erase`).

Comment: @Jefffrey: If he keeps the reference around, he will have the same problem as pointer or iterator invalidation. He's quite right that this is something you have to be aware of.

Comment: @user1014679 if you need to perform modifications, it might be better to use an *associative container*, like `unordered_map` instead.

Comment: Isn't passing vector indexes between methods kind of messy?

Comment: @user1014679: Use iterators or pointers/references instead, that's what they're for. You can use smart pointers if you're concerned about pointer invalidation. `unique_ptr` is well suited here.

Comment: @user1014679 Depends. Again, if you can assign an id to every object, keeping them in an associative container can make access and ownership more transparent. Or, instead of assigning an `id`, define *equality* between two objects and keep them in a `set`.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

This means your `i` and `e` iterators have both been invalidated. So don't use `erase` inside a loop like you're doing!

Also consider:

1. Using smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr` instead of doing memory management yourself.
2. Looking up the [erase-remove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), though it isn't quite so useful here because:
3. You're deleting every element in the vector. You don't need to erase them as you go along, just use `m_vActiveB.clear()` when you've deleted them all, but you don't even need to do that because:
4. This is a destructor and `m_vActiveB` is a member. It'll get tidied up for you, don't bother clearing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::vector::erase` causes iterators at and past the point of erase to become invalidated. As such happens, the past-the-end iterator `e` is no longer valid after the first iteration.

Instead compare directly against the iterator returned from `std::vector::end` at every iteration. However, in your example there's no need to erase anything as `m_vActiveB` is a member and will be destructed automatically after running the dtor (`delete`ing the data pointed *to* is however required).

The iterator `i` will also become invalidated when the erase happens as making a copy `tmp` of the iterator `i` and erasing it will still cause the same element to be erased from the vector (erasing a copy of an iterator does not help).

```
ClassA::~ClassA() {
    for (vector<ClassB*>::iterator i = m_vActiveB.begin(); i != m_vActiveB.end(); ++i) {
        //vector<ClassB*>::iterator tmp(i++); // Unnecessary
        delete *i;
        //m_vActiveB.erase(i); // Unnecessary as elements will be erased automatically.
    }
}
```

Equivalent C++11 code:

```
ClassA::~ClassA() {
    for (auto ptr : m_vActiveB) {
        delete ptr;
    }
}
```

A better alternative would be to use a C++11 smart pointer as e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, that can handle the allocation and deallocation automatically.

```
class ClassA {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ClassB>> m_vActiveB; // No need for explicit destructor.
    /* ... */
};
```

Or if you are not using polymorphism or have some other specific reason to use pointers, then why use pointers at all? Simply use a `std:vector<ClassB>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing elements from the vector while iterating through it. That invalidates the iterators.

It should be something like this:

```
ClassA::~ClassA() 
{
    for (auto e : m_vActiveB)
    {
        delete e;
    }
}
```

You don't have to clear the vector, it is destroyed anyway after the destructor has finished.

Comment: It should not be anything like this at all. The OP should use smart pointers.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `vector::erase`, it invalidates any other iterator into the vector.

So you cannot use a "traditional" iterator loop.

The simplest way is as Rakibul Hasan suggests, just delete all pointers and then `clear` the vector.

Comment: In this case, there's no point clearing the vector, since it's about to be destroyed.

Comment: Fair enough, although for anyone else searching for how to clear a vector of pointers which own their content; it'd be useful for them to read that the technique is to delete them all and then clear.